# SwiftUI: Custom table view cell with content aligned to the center

Tags: uitableview, swiftui, alignment, swift5, xcode11

I'm new to SwiftUI and was wondering how to center the content (horizontally and vertically) inside my table view cells. My current code is as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    List(list) { item in
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image(systemName: item.imageName)
            Text(item.text)
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to align the VStack in the center of the cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach (`alignment: .center` is by default, so can be dropped)

```
List(list) { item in
    HStack {
      Spacer()
      VStack {
        Image(systemName: item.imageName)
        Text(item.text)
      }
      Spacer()
    }
}
```